# Mathematical formulation of LPP

Tags: linear-programming

I want to formulate the following problem as a LPP

A manufacturing company produces two types of computer monitor- color and monochrome. The data in the manufacturing context are as follows

1. 6 days are required to complete one unit of each type of monitors and only 240 working days are available in a year.
2. The profit for a color monitor is Rs 1500 and that for monochrome is Rs 1000
3. The marketting department reports that only 20 units of color and 30 units of monochrome monitors can be sold in a year.

My formulation is :

Let $x_1$ units of color monitors and $x_2$ units of monochrome should be manufactured. Then

Max $z=1500x_1+1000x_2$

subject to

$6x_1+6x_2\leq 240$

$x_1\leq 20$

$x_2\leq 30$

$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$

Is is correct?

Comment: Yes , it's right.